# SAS %if macros not resolving based on other conditions

Tags: sas

I have this macro that doesn't resolve even if the logic seems to work. I'm a beginner sas user so the code might look a little messy.

```
%let macro1 = 1600;
%let macro2 = 1300;

%if '&macro1.' > '&macro2.' %then %do;
   %let macro3 = increase;
%else %if '&macro1.' < '&macro2.' %then %do;
   %let macro3 = decrease;
%else %if '&macro1.' = '&macro2.' %then %do;
   %let macro3 = stability;
%end;
```

when I run the code, there are no errors but macro3 does not resolve and it looks something like:

"There is a &macro3. between 1600 and 1300"

Comment: Is your real code missing all of the semicolons like your posted code?  Do you really have `&` inside of single quotes?  Macro triggers are not resolved inside of single quotes.

Comment: If you are a beginning SAS user then do not bother with macro code.  Learn how to write actual SAS code before you starting trying to use the macro processor to generate your SAS code.

Comment: @Tom no, my actual code isn't missing all the semicolons, I was typing it out too quickly and missed those. I am having issues with this because it was working at one point but after making some edits, something must've changed for it to stop working and it is a struggle to find where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `%END;` statements for the `%DO;` statements.  Do you really need the `%DO;` statements? You don't appear to be trying to run multiple statements when the condition is true.

The macro processor will ignore macro triggers that are inside quoted strings that are bounded by single quote characters.  So the result of your tests will always be that the string `'&macro1'` is less than the string `'&macro2'` because the digit 1 comes before the digit 2 in lexicographical ordering.

Either remove the quotes completely or replace them with double quote characters.

Without the quotes the implied `%EVAL()` macro function call will compare the strings `1600` and `1300` as integer numbers.  With the quotes then %EVAL() will compare the string `"1600"` and `"1300"` as character strings.

So if the values of MACRO1 and MACRO2 are supposed to be numbers then do not include the quotes in the `%IF` conditions.  Otherwise values like `"1200"` will be less that values like `"800"` becuase `8` is larger than `1`.

You also have to wrap the whole sequence of %IF/%THEN/%ELSE/%IF inside a macro definition, if it is not already inside of a macro definition, because you cannot have nested %IF in open code.

```
%macro testit;
%let macro1 = 1600;
%let macro2 = 1300;

%if &macro1. > &macro2. %then %let macro3 = increase;
%else %if &macro1. < &macro2. %then %let macro3 = decrease;
%else %let macro3 = stability;
%put &=macro3 ;
%mend testit;

%testit;
```

And if &MACRO1 and &MACRO2 are not INTEGER values then you will need to explicitly use %SYSEVALF() to compare them.

```
%let macro1 = 16.50;
%let macro2 = 13.00;

%if %sysevalf(&macro1. > &macro2.) %then  ....
```

Comment: thank you, I wasn't aware of how SAS looks at different types of macros. I tried the double quotes at first and noticed that some places the wording was still incorrect, that was because the macros are supposed to be integers so I've removed all quotations and everything is well

Comment: It is not the macro variables, but the code you used the macro variables to generate.  Try it without the macro variables.  Compare `%if 1200 < 800 ...` to `%if "1200" < "800" ... `